# Python del and garbage collecting

Tags: python, garbage-collection, del

First look at my Python code,

```
s = [[1, 2], [3, 6], [9, 6]]
t = s
i = s[0]

del i
del t[0]
```

There is three references for [2, 1]; t[0], s[0] and "i", so if we try and delete of them it shouldn't effect on [1,2] because [1,2] still has two another reference so Python garbage-collection system doesn't
remove [1,2] do to the having no reference. So why deleting "i" doesn't
effect on [1,2] but deleting t[0] does.

Comment: Setting a variable equal to anther list does not copy the list, it only sets a reference in memory. When you edit the reference, you edit the original list. Use the copy module to actually copy the list.

Comment: I know that, but I'm not editing, I'm deleting one of references.

Comment: `del container[key]` will delete the element in the container, but `del variable_name` will only delete the name.

Comment: No, not one of the references, because there's only one.

Comment: *but in the second case when I try to delete "i" nothing happen to [1, 2]* - No because `i` is the value `[1, 2]` which was the value of s[0], this is not longer a reference.

Comment: In the second example nothing happens because you are deleting a reference to an element (this does not delete the element), while in the first you are deleting the element itself.

Comment: Like @MechanicPig said: `del container[key]` removes a key from a container, but `del variable_name` removes a variable from the namespace.  It might be clearer to think of these as two separate operations that happen to share the same keyword `del`.

Comment: How are you testing whether garbage collection happens?

Comment: @slothrop: del container[key] just delete key not the value so s[0] should not changed.

Comment: If `l` is a list, then `del l[i]` deletes the item at position `i`.  So `del t[0]` deletes the first element of `t`.  `s` is a reference to the same list object that `t` refers to, so after the deletion, `s[0]` is the same as new `t[0]`, which is the previous `t[1]`.

Comment: @slothrop, as I find out, "del" has different functionality in different situation. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistakenly understand the function of the `del` statement. For variable names:

```
del variable_name
```

The `del` statement deletes the binding of the name to the object from the global variable.

For the combination of container and key:

```
del container[key]
```

It is responsible for deleting the elements in the container according to the key.

Use some simple symbols to explain what you are doing. Here I use a pair of parentheses to represent an object, and a word `ref` or a variable name represents a reference. After you create these objects, it will look like this:

```
 t s
 ↓ ↓
(list [ref, ref])
 i ┌───┘    └───────┐
 ↓ ↓                ↓
(list [ref, ref]) (list [ref, ref])
   ┌───┘  ┌─┘     ┌──────┘┌───┘
   ↓      ↓       ↓       ↓
(int 1) (int 2) (int 3) (int 6)
```

If you execute `del i`, the final result is as follows:

```
 t s
 ↓ ↓
(list [ref, ref])
   ┌───┘    └───────┐
   ↓                ↓
(list [ref, ref]) (list [ref, ref])
   ┌───┘  ┌─┘     ┌──────┘┌───┘
   ↓      ↓       ↓       ↓
(int 1) (int 2) (int 3) (int 6)
```

If you execute `del t[0]`, the final result is as follows:

```
 t s
 ↓ ↓
(list [ref])
 i     └────────────┐
 ↓                  ↓
(list [ref, ref]) (list [ref, ref])
   ┌───┘  ┌─┘     ┌──────┘┌───┘
   ↓      ↓       ↓       ↓
(int 1) (int 2) (int 3) (int 6)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so "del" has different functionality respect to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment to answer.

Setting a variable equal to anther list does not copy the list, it only sets a reference in memory. When you edit the reference, you edit the original list. Use the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) to actually copy the list.

Example:

```
import copy

s = [[1, 2], [3, 6], [9, 6]]
t = copy.copy(s)
del t[0]

print(s)
print(t)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 6], [9, 6]]
[[3, 6], [9, 6]]
```

**Note**:

`copy.copy()` Is a shallow copy that constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

`copy.deepcopy()` Is a deep copy that constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: I don't want copy the list, I just want know s[0] and t[0] is a reference for [1, 2] or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `t[0]` is a reference to `s[0]` which holds the value `[1, 2]`.

Comment: There is three reference for [1,2];  t[0], s[0] and "i" is a reference for [1,2] so by deleting one of them, [1,2] should stile exist because it stile have two another reference so python garbage-collection system shouldn't remove it. but it happen when when try del t[0].

Comment: When you set `i` equal to a value in a list, this variable is not a reference to the list, but merely a new variable containing the value of `s[0]`.

Comment: @SiavashMoghadas This has nothing to do with garbage collection. It simply deletes the element from the list `t`, and the element itself is not collected.

Comment: @mechanic-pig so why when still [1,2] has another reference it should be gone?

Comment: @SiavashMoghadas This is what the `del container[key]` statement does. It deletes elements from the container.

Comment: @mechanic-pig so t[0] is more than a reference? it delete the actual value it is trying to reference. I think something is not right. but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`i = s[0]` will set i to be equal to [1,2].
So, now we have i = [1,2]
When you use `del i`, that does not affect the original list. It only affects the variable `i`
If you want to delete the first item in the list `s`, you can just do this:

```
del s[0]
```

But, also note that it better to use `remove()` in this case since the time complexity of `remove()` is `O(n)`where `n` is the number of elements and `del` has a time complexity of `O(n-1)` where is the index of the element to be deleted

Comment: If `i` is 0, then `n-i` is equal to `n`: so it doesn't seem like `del` would have a higher time complexity than `remove`?

Comment: @slothrop Actually, it is O(n-1). Sorry about that :)

Comment: anything based on indexing is just O(n-1)

Comment: In big-O notation, we just care about the dominant term, so we wouldn't write something like `O(n-1)`, it would just be `O(n)`.  Deletion of a list item should be `O(n)` as per: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: In any case, `n-1` is smaller than `n`, so this wouldn't explain `remove` being faster than `del`.

Comment: @slothrop You are right! Thanh you for the clarification

Comment: Cool.  One way to think about this is - `remove` has to do two things: (1) find the position of the item, then (2) delete it.  So `del` should be faster, because it can skip that first step of finding the position: when we do `del s[0]` we tell Python explicitly that the element is at position 0.

Comment: @slothrop YES! that is exactly what I meant!! Just couldn't turn my thoughts into words :)